# Does KDE sensor Gnome apps – where's Gnome Terminal?

Tags: gnome, kde

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and trying to use KDE desktop (I've just installed the package `kde-full` and switched to KDE/Plasma session from the login manager). I find that the KDE default terminal app Konsole is inferior to Gnome Terminal but I cannot find the Gnome Terminal from the KDE / start menu even though I can start it from command line running `gnome-terminal`. I've never noticed that Xfce or MATE or Gnome 3 or Cinnamon were hiding any installed apps from their respective menus even if those apps were competition for their respective apps.

I know I could create a custom launcher to get the Gnome Terminal to appear again but is this a common thing with KDE to sensor competing Gnome apps? Is there some setting that allows me to restore all Gnome apps to be included in the All Applications list in the KDE menu?